# Send data in chunks with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, streaming

I'm quite new to nodejs and I'm working on a backend for an Angular 4 application. The problem is that the backend is quite slow to produce the whole data for the response and I'd like to send data over time as soon as it's available. I was reading about RxJS but I can't really figure out how to use it in node, can you please help me?

Comment: `res.write()` will send a piece of the response.  You can call it as many times as you need to and then call `res.end()` when done.

Comment: @jfriend00 what he really needs is get them delivered as soon as available, so `res.write(chunk)` followed `res.flush()` to deliver the chunk as soon as the chunks are available, and when ended , then `res.end()` is performed.

Comment: I'm now using socket.io and it's working very well!

Comment: another super nodejs websocket lib is ws   https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for a way to **stream** the data

## Express

Normally you respond with `res.send(data)`, it can be called only once.

If you are reading and sending a large file, you can **stream** the file data while being read with `res.write(chunk)` and on the 'end' event of the file reading, you call `res.end()` to end the response.

---

**EDIT** : As you state, what you want is to stream as soon as the chunk is available, so you can use the `res.flush()` command between writes ( just flush after `res.write(chunk)`).

It would be much faster in your case but the overall compression will be much less efficient.

Comment: Yeah, but in this way I still receive the data only when the end method is called (all at once)

Comment: It will still be much faster than with res.send(data)

Comment: In my case some data is available after half a second and some after 5 seconds. Using this method I still get all the data after 5 seconds, which is not what I need

Comment: If you want to stream, you can use the res.flush() command between writes, but the compression will be much less efficient.

Comment: @lpeppe did you try with res.flush() (as the last edit to my answer mentions) ?