# res.write() is sending concatenated data

Tags: node.js, express, https

i am using an express node server and i want to receive response in chunks at client. but i am receiving concatenated data like i have a loop a at server end and at each index i am doing res.write(index) like this

```
    for(let index = 0; index <= 10; index+){
       res.write(index)
    }
```

but instead of getting single index at client each time i get a response it contains all previous responses concatenated as well for example for first time i get 1.for second time i get 12.third time i get 123 and so on.
at client i am receiving res like this

```
    axios.post(url, body, {
        onDownloadProgress: progressEvent => {
        const dataChunk = progressEvent.currentTarget.response;
        //chunky response here
        //here i am getting concatenated data
    );
        },
        timeout: 600000
    })
        .then((response) => {
              //final response here
             })
```

Comment: maybe try `res.send(index)`

Comment: i did but i think it sends the final response because the second time i do res.send(index) it says headers cannot be set after res has already been sent or something like this.

Comment: Try using `res.flush(index)` You can read more here
[Send data in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45849147/send-data-in-chunks-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

The server's stream can aggregate the chunks in any way it sees fit, and the client is free to buffer them as well, so you will not get per-message semantics this way. See this SO question for an example of what other trouble you may encounter: [How to flush chunks of arbitrary sizes in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184103/how-to-flush-chunks-of-arbitrary-sizes-in-nodejs)

If you are looking to send separate messages to the client, you have several options:

- Use a streamable data format, such as YAML (with document separators) or XML (and a streaming parser on the client)
- Use a more suitable protocol: [Server-Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) or [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)
- Use a cross-transport messaging library such as `socket.io`